# How to make an asynchronous loop with callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, callback, closures

I have a problem where the order of de index of the loop keeps changing in the callback. See the code below for what I've tried, the goal I'm trying to achieve is to add markers based on the available layers. However the order on which I loop over the layers has to be the same order in which I add the markers. Later on, when I fix this problem, the goal is that users can click on a generated marker what will result in a layer that opens with information. Does anyone know what the solution is? I've experimented with the comments of @patrickRoberts and @stian.

```
$(function(){

//  I've tried the following:
//  – async/await with promises
//  – JavaScript Closures
//  – Closures with IIFE (see example below)

'use strict';

//Cache DOM
let $win                = $(window),
    $doc                = $(document),
    $body               = $('body'),
    $layer              = $('.layer'),
    $drawingImage       = $('.drawings__image'),
    $markerContainer    = $('.markers');

//Init
_addMarkers();

function _addMarkers(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $layer.length; i++){
        //Right order
        console.log(i);

        (function(i){
            _calculateScaleFactor($drawingImage.eq(0), function(data){

                //Wrong order
                console.log(i);
            });
        })(i);
    }
}

function _createMarker(x, y, ){
    return $(`<span class="markers__single-marker" style="left:${x}px; top:${y}px;">${i}</span>`);
}

function _calculateScaleFactor(image, callback){
    let newImage    = new Image();

    newImage.src = image.attr('src');
    newImage.onload = function(){
        let scaleFactor = newImage.width / image.width();
        callback(scaleFactor);
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Why does the order need to be the same? You already have a reference to the index, so it might just be easier to use that than to rely on the callbacks being invoked in order.

Comment: Because otherwise the corrected layerData.x and layerData.y won't keep their value.

Comment: Ah, the reason why is because you have an `append()` function that requires the correct order of execution. Unfortunately `$.each()` does not have an option to respect asynchronous execution, so you'll need to move away from using that to iterate your elements, or you should use it to iterate the resulting array of `scaleFactor`s after the initial asynchronous iteration has been completed.

Comment: Oh okay, let me try to separate the two functionalities. The first one for creating an array with the correct layerData for each data and the second one for adding the layer marks. I'll let you if this wil fix my issue. Thanks in advance! 

On another note, are you for hire? I'm currently quite low capacity and looking for an extra pair of hands.

Comment: I've just tried to separate the two functions however this doesn't seem to solve my problem. I made a for loop to fill up an array with the marker positions however, still because of the onload, the order in which the marker positions are stored is continually changing. Any other advice @PatrickRoberts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of experimenting (with no await/async experience at all) I finally fixed it with the async and await. Special thanks to @stian! Hope that the solution also wil help others, see code below:

```
$(function(){

'use strict';

//Cache DOM
let $win                = $(window),
    $doc                = $(document),
    $body               = $('body'),
    $layer              = $('.layer'),
    $drawingImage       = $('.drawings__image'),
    $markerContainer    = $('.markers');

//Init
_addMarkers();

async function _addMarkers(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $layer.length; i++){
        let _self = $layer.eq(i),
            layerData = {
                x: _self.data('x'),
                y: _self.data('y')
            }
        await _calculateScaleFactor($drawingImage.eq(0)).then(function(resolve){
            layerData.x = (layerData.x / resolve) + $drawingImage.eq(0).offset().left;
            layerData.y = (layerData.y / resolve) + $drawingImage.eq(0).offset().top;

            $markerContainer.append( _createMarker(layerData.x, layerData.y, i) );
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
}

function _createMarker(x, y, i){
    return $(`<span class="markers__single-marker" style="left:${x}px; top:${y}px;">${i}</span>`);
}

function _calculateScaleFactor(image){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let newImage    = new Image();

        newImage.src = image.attr('src');
        newImage.onload = function(){
            let scaleFactor = newImage.width / image.width();
            resolve(scaleFactor);
        }
    });
}
```

})

Answer (score -1):

Here is a away to do it with async/await and promises. Hope it's useful.

```
$(() => {
  //your array of elements
  let arr = ["hello", "hi", "bye"]
  calculate(arr)

})

async function calculate(arr){

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    console.log(i, arr[i])
    let result = await someAsyncStuff(arr[i])
    console.log(i, result)
  }

}

function someAsyncStuff(el){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //your async code here
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, el)
  })
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { resolve(el) }, 2000)` -> `setTimeout(resolve, 2000, el)`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @stian I've tried the following but probably I'm doing something wrong. Can I share my use case code with you? Right now i get a 'await is only valid in async function' error. I don't have any experience with the async/await functions.

Comment: I'm having some problems understanding what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get a scale factor that is the same for every image? or are you trying to get a new scaling factor for every image?

Comment: @stian First of all thank you for offering your help! Let me shortly tell you about the project. I'm looping over multiple layers (div's with content and data attributes), within this loop I'll check each layer for its data-x and data-y attribute. These attributes contain values which corresponds to a position on an image. Because the images are responsive I have to calculate the corrected X and Y value. Then for each layer I create a marker that show's the layer when a user clicks it. Although I've still some other work to do you can see an example here: https://www.futurevisuals.nl/flatland/